# PHP: Passing additional parameters through "form"

Tags: php, html

I am using simple radio button form to pass parameter "mode" to "script.php". How can I pass additional custom parameters when I click "submit" button?

```
<form action="./script.php">
<p>2) Select mode:</p>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="maps">full<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="backup">partial<br> 
<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="Decrypt">
</form>
```

Comment: Add `<input type="hidden">`.

Comment: Why downvotes?!

Comment: Yes, thanks, I already got answer below. You can help me in the comments though. ;) @Arnavion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take `<input type="hidden" name="parameter_name" value="your_custom_value">` to pass additional parameter value inside form

And completely your form will be like this...

```
<form action="./script.php">
<p>2) Select mode:</p>
<input type="hidden" name="parameter_name"  value="your_custom_value">
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="maps">full<br>
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="backup">partial<br> 
<p></p>
<input type="submit" value="Decrypt">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question! If I may expand question - the page where this runs also has upload script. I want to pass uploaded file's name as this additional parameter. How can I take variable containing file name (in php) and pass it in this html script? Thanks!